# Efficient way to manipulate threads RxJava

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java

In my project I need to process objects in different threads. To manipulate stream's behaviour I create new observables to change their `observeOn()` this way:

```
apiService.getObjects(token) // Retrofit
                .compose(bindToLifecycle())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(o -> {
                    // process in Main Thread
                })
                .map(Observable::just)  // create new one, to change thread for it
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
                .subscribe(o -> {
                    // process in the background thread
                });
```

But I think in RxJava there is much more beautiful and efficient way to process one response in different threads. I tried to google it, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks,
Anton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rx, it's usually recommended to avoid side effects in 'do' blocks (which will only be executed if the stream gets subscribed on), and prefer subscribe code.

In your case you can leverage [`cache()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#cache()) or `publish()...connect()`, e.g:

```
query = apiService.getObjects(token)
            .compose(bindToLifecycle())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .cache();

query.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(o -> {
                // process in Main Thread
            })
query.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(o -> {
                // process in the background thread
            });
```

With `publish()` instead of `cache()`, the code is identical but you can decide when to fire your query by *connecting* the stream (you call `query.connect()` after wiring up the 2 subscriptions).

If your subscription work is background computation, `Schedulers.computation()` may be preferred over `Schedulers.io()`.

Note that AFAICT your code will work just fine without the `map(Observable::just)` line, as 'observeOn' statements only impact the stream further down (and not previous 'do' statements)

Comment: How does computation work? And can you explain publish -> connect?